# how can i separate one month and correspond variables in R?

Tags: r

[image]

I want to separate Time.Month.th in to 2, 1 stand for january, 2 stand for feb. i want to extract 3 column(Time.Month.th  and Temp and BFS) based on the month i separate.  I use R program

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to generate 2 dataframes, one for data for January and the second for February.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame("Time.Month_th" = c(1,1,2,2), "BFS" = c(197,365,496,441), "Temp" = c(16.4,15.3,16.8,16.1))

df_january <-df %>%
    filter(Time.Month_th=="1") %>%
    select(Time.Month_th, Temp, BFS)

df_february <-df %>%
    filter(Time.Month_th=="2") %>%
    select(Time.Month_th, Temp, BFS)
```

Comment: yes, i want to create two dataframe, but when i use your method, it appear that [Error in UseMethod("filter") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "function"]

Answer (score 0):

We could use `split` in `base R`

```
lst1 <- split(df[c('Time.Month.th', 'Temp', 'BFS')], df$Time.Month_th)
```